# Can someone briefly explain me what's the difference between Exact Factor Model (EFM) and Approximate Factor Model (AFM)?

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory

I'm reading De Nard et al. paper ["Portfolio Selection in Large Dimensions"](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3194492) and the authors talk about these two models, but I don't have any background on these topics from university. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

On Page 4 "An exact factor model assumes in addition that Σu is a diagonal matrix. In contrast, an approximate factor model only assumes that Σu is a matrix with bounded L 1 or L 2 norm" for example, see Connor and Korajczyk (1993), Bai and Ng (2002), Fan et al. (2008), and the references therein." So the difference is: are the residual or idiosyncractic terms orthogonal or not.

In an exact factor model all the common influences on the stocks are accounted for by the known factors; what is left are random uncorrelated movements of each stock. In an approximate factor model the known factors take care of some of the common movements, but some stocks still tend to move together for other reasons, possibly because of omitted or unknown factors.

Comment: Current research in portfolio management emphasizes factor models, so I recommend studying up on them if you want to be able to read the literature.